# How to add .env file & host React app in Netlify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify

I have a React app that is present in GitHub and I want to host it with help with Netlify, where I am not sure where should I place my `.env` file which contains all the credentials for API

Comment: Your API credentials shouldn't be in your React app at all.

Comment: typically the user of your app should login and acquire a token or cookie and with that you can manage API access.

Comment: What about the The APi that I use in my application I am asking on that , For Example API that I have used like MailAPI that I am using which I have stored in .ENV where can I place it on netlify to make it work the way it does in Local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Netlify, on your product page.

Go to 'Site Settings' -> 'Build & Deploy' and scroll down to 'Environment'. You can input your env variables here.

Never upload your .env file to GitHub.